# Get URL Parameters Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url, parameters

I am trying to get the ULR parameter, but my code does not run because at debugging it shows me an error which is: `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`
and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
For example: `default.html?pid=405` I need to get in a JavaScript variable the `405` value. This is the code i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode) {
        var currLocation = (staticURL.length) ? staticURL : window.location.search,
            parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
            returnBool = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++) {
            parr = parArr[i].value.split("=");
            if (parr[0] == parameter) {
                return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
                returnBool = true;
            } else {
                returnBool = false;
            }
        }

        if (!returnBool) return false;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function runDepo()
    {
        var idParameter = getUrlParameters("pid", "", true);
    }
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line is throwing that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: parr = parArr[i].value.split("=");

Comment: It's not a duplicate

Comment: If `parArr` is actually an array then you would just use `parArr[i].split("=")`

Comment: This is not a duplicate because I need to create that function and call the variable in a another function, besides my issue is that the script is showing me an error which is NOT RECOGNIZE the split!! THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!

Comment: I also tried ´parArr[i].split("=")´ but it still showing me the same error

Comment: check what is the value that `window.location.search` returns. Because if neither window.location.search nor staticURL have a `?`, it will crash when accessing the first position of the array

Comment: @Lanshore No need to yell. Notice that they said "possible duplicate." And it's not the `split` isn't recognized, it's that you're trying to use `split` on `undefined`. It's the same thing as typing `undefined.split('=')`.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `.value` from `parr = parArr[i].value.split("=");`

```js
function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode) {
        var currLocation = (staticURL.length) ? staticURL : window.location.search,
            parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
            returnBool = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++) {
            parr = parArr[i].split("=");
            if (parr[0] == parameter) {
                return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
                returnBool = true;
            } else {
                returnBool = false;
            }
        };

        if (!returnBool) return false;
    };
    
    document.getElementById('Result').value = getUrlParameters("pid", "default.html?pid=405", true);

    alert(getUrlParameters("pid", "default.html?pid=405", true));
```

```html
PID : <input type="text" id="Result" placeholder="Result">
```

Comment: I tried this, but should I have to code this `alert(getUrlParameters("pid", "default.html?pid=405", true));` is there any way not to have to write it?

Comment: @Lanshore no it's just for testing functionality, but where do you want displaying result ?

Comment: Post this as answer, I cannot answer myself, I solved it by my own.

Comment: `function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = {};
                var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                    vars[key] = value;
                });
                return vars;
            }


            var first = getUrlVars()["pid"];`

Comment: This is a better way to get what I needed.